# sumar variables de una función dentro de otra - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy aprendiendo Python, arranque hace unas semanas. Este es el primer programa "grande" (no se rían los más experimentados) que estoy haciendo.
El problema planteado es este:

Gestione un restaurante, para ello se seguirán las siguientes instrucciones:
El restaurante dispone de una carta de 10 comidas, de las cuales debemos saber:
el nombre, el precio de venta y el tipo de comida que es (aperitivo, carne, pescado, postre).
Se debe poder añadir, modificar o eliminar cualquier plato de la carta.
Cuando se realiza un pedido se introducirán los platos requeridos y al final se mostrará por pantalla el precio total.
Cuando se cierra el restaurante el programa mostrará por pantalla el dinero total ganado.

Hasta los primeros pasos, funciona perfecto. 
Tengo que leer un poco mas de teoría, no entiendo del todo cuando una función precisa un parámetro y cuándo no. Más allá de eso, el problema lo tengo en la última parte: calcular la caja.

No sé como hacer para llamar la variable "***total***", que se encuentra dentro de la función **pedidos** en otra función que pienso llamar "**caja**". Probé de varias formas y siempre me da error.  Tampoco entiendo como hacer para llamar la variable ***total*** para la mesa 1 y para la mesa 2. Es decir, caja debería ser la suma del ***total*** de **pedidos(1)** y el ***total*** de **pedidos(2)**

Les agradezco de antemano por la ayuda. Disculpen si no soy claro, todavía estoy medio perdido con algunos términos.

```
#funciones del programa
def menu(nombre, precio, tipo):
    for x in range(listadeprecios):
        nombre.append(input("ingrese el nombre del plato: "))
        precio.append(float(input("Ingrese el precio del plato: ")))
        tipo.append(input("ingrese el tipo del plato: "))
        return nombre, precio, tipo
def anadir(nombre, precio, tipo):
    seguir = input("Desea actulizar el menu? s/n: ".lower())
    while (seguir == "s"):
        nombre.append(input("ingrese el nombre del plato: "))
        precio.append(float(input("Ingrese el precio del plato: ")))            
        tipo.append(input("ingrese el tipo del plato: "))
        seguir = input("Quiere ingresar otro plato? s/n: ").lower()
        return nombre, precio, tipo
def eliminar():
    seguir = input("Desea eliminar un plato? s/n: ".lower())
    while (seguir == "s"):
        plato_a_eliminar = input("ingrese el nombre del plato a eliminar: ")
        posicion = nombre.index(plato_a_eliminar)
        nombre.remove(plato_a_eliminar)
        precio.pop(posicion)
        tipo.pop(posicion)
        seguir = input("Desea eliminar otro plato? s/n: ".lower())
def modificar():
    seguir = input("Desea modificar el menu? s/n: ".lower())
    while (seguir == "s"):
        plato_a_modificar = input("ingrese el plato a modificar: ")
        posicion = nombre.index(plato_a_modificar)
        nombre[posicion] = input("ingrese el nombre del plato: ")
        precio[posicion] = float(input("ingrese el precio del plato: "))
        tipo[posicion] = input("ingrese el tipo de plato: ")
        seguir = input("Quiere modificar otro plato? s/n: ").lower()
def pedidos(numero_mesa):
    seguir  = 's'
    total = 0
    while(seguir=='s'):
        pedido = input("Que desea ordenar?: ")
        if pedido in nombre:
            posicion = nombre.index(pedido)
            total = total + precio[posicion]
            seguir = input("Quiere pedir algo mas? s/n: ").lower()
        else:
            print("Te pido disculpas, nos quedamos sin ", pedido)
    print("Su ticket es de: ", total)



#PROGRAMA PRINCIPAL
nombre = []
precio = []
tipo = []
listadeprecios = 1
menu(nombre, precio, tipo)
pedidos(1)
pedidos(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo hice con listas y funciono. PD: a la funcion pedidos no hace falta pasarle ningun parametro.

```
def pedidos():
    seguir  = 's'
    total = 0
    while (seguir=='s'):
        pedido = input("Que desea ordenar?: ")
        if pedido in nombre:
            posicion = nombre.index(pedido)
            total = total + precio[posicion]
            seguir = input("Quiere pedir algo mas? s/n: ").lower()
        else:
            print("Te pido disculpas, nos quedamos sin ", pedido)
    total1.append(total)
    print("Su ticket es de: ", total)
    print(total1)

def caja():
        caja = 0
        for i in range(len(total1)):
            caja = caja + total1[i]
        print("La caja del dia es: ", caja)
```